# How to check whether a snapshot with ID is in use of AWS AMI's in Boto?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto

I am getting the following Error while deleting snapshots. I wanted to delete Snapshot which are currently not in use by My AWS AMI's and Other Instances.. as well .I tried but got this error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
<path to error file>
EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidSnapshot.InUse</Code><Message>The snapshot snap-xxxxxxxx is currently in use by ami-xxxxxxxx</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>bbe55333-4acf-4ca7-9aa3-49307b189ca3</RequestID></Response>
```

Comment: Can you post some code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not an API to get AMI ID directly from an EBS snapshot.

Instead, you can go the other way.

1. Use `ec2:DescribeImages` to get a list of AMI images.
2. For each AMI image returned, examine the list of EBS snapshots associated with the AMI image.
3. See if the EBS snapshot in question is included.

**Edit: Another possibility:**

You may be able to use `ec2:DescribeImages` with a filter on the EBS snapshot ID.

```
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeImages
 &Filter.1.Name=block-device-mapping.snapshot-id
 &Filter.1.Value=snap-xxxx
```

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImages.html

Answer (score 2):

Delete all Snapshots which are not in use :

```
for s in $(comm -23 <(echo $(ec2-describe-snapshots --region ap-southeast-1 | grep SNAPSHOT | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq) | tr ' ' '\n') <(echo $(ec2-describe-images --region ap-southeast-1 | grep BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq) | tr ' ' '\n') | tr '\n' ' ')
do
    echo Deleting snapshot $s
    ec2-delete-snapshot --region ap-southeast-1 $s  
done
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Retrieve all the Snapshots, Use regular expression to search for AMI-ID inside snapshot description.

```
    reAmi = re.compile('ami-[^ ]+')
    snapshotImageId = reAmi.findall(snapshot.description)
```

2) Retrieve all the AMI's. Check whether the AMI-ID retrieved in first step still exist, if not then snapshot associated with that particular AMI is no longer required.

complete code is posted [here](https://gist.github.com/mjbommar/5070899)

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone still wondering how to do it:

```
def if_associated_to_ami(client, snapshot_id):
  img = client.describe_images(
      Filters=[
          {'Name': 'block-device-mapping.snapshot-id', 'Values': [snapshot_id]}
      ]
  )
  try:
      ami_id = img['Images'][0]['ImageId']
      print("Snapshot(" + snapshot_id + ") is associated to image(" + ami_id + "). Return True")
      return True
  except IndexError:
      print("Snapshot(" + snapshot_id + ") is not associated to any image. Return False")
      return False
```